# What is special in 22?

Tags: number, mysticism-kabbalah

The Hebrew alphabet has 22 letters and according to Kabbalah everything has been created on a spiritual level by those 22 forces. But what exactly?

Some teachers say we've 22 chromosomes, but I don't agree, as we've 23 pairs of chromosomes (total of 46). So I can't see any other connections of 22 to the Universe (in terms of the forces or building blocks).

**What is special in 22 (twenty two) or what's the deeper meaning of it?**

Similar as we've 12 months based on the Moon's phases (12 lunar cycles in a solar year; [twelve Shevatim](http://www.cckollel.org/parsha_encounters/5767/vayigash.pdf)) and we've [12 hours to the day, 12 hours to the night](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4792/12-hours-to-the-day-12-hours-to-the-night) (based on different constellations of the sky), etc.

The topic was discussed at The Kabbalah Centre classes. Please check the [podcast](https://www.mediafire.com/?76g6pqgpbr2723j) at around *16:05*, *52:00* minutes (*22 forces = 22 building blocks*).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1140/shnayim-veesrim-mi-yodeya

Comment: @Cnsersmoit Dupe?

Comment: @DoubleAA I can't tell if this question just wants any info on 22, or only Kabbalistic interpretations.

Comment: I'm expecting Kabbalistic interpretations. The other question doesn't ask for any explanation (interpretation of 22 building blocks) and answers on the questions are very short without any further details.

Comment: Note that 22 pairs are equal pairs. One pair is the sex based determinant where the X and Y differ in order to produce a male with an XY pair and a female with an XX pair. Thus, we have 22 fundamental pairs and an additional specific pair. perhaps the 22 fundamental pairs are the "forces".

Comment: Or primarily opinion based

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here. Are you just interested in things that are 22?

Comment: @Daniel According to Kaballah, there are 22 universal forces (aka 22 building blocks). But apart of 22 Hebrew letters, I don't see any other connections of 22 with anything. So I'm hoping that somebody can point it out what's so special in 22, maybe I missed something.

Comment: So the answer to my question is "yes"?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I'm interested in universal 22 things related to these 22 universal forces.

Comment: Then this question is _way_ to broad.

Comment: @Daniel How come, if my question is specifically about 22 universal forces? And somehow [Who knows twenty-two?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1140/6557) isn't too broad?

Comment: What's the difference between this question and that one? You haven't explained what a "universal force" is, so as far as I can tell, this question is just asking for things with the number 22 in them, but not even restricting those things to things related to Judaism.

Comment: @Daniel By universal force I mean life-force energy (Shefa or Nefesh/Chi).

Comment: Try some of the things here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/22_(number) They are allegedly significant.

Answer (score 1):

There are 22 (proteinogenic) amino acids - "the building blocks of life". http://aminoacidstudies.org/#sthash.51ThyP74.dpuf

Comment: Good try, but the source is saying that there are over 200 different amino acids, however these 22 are the most well known, so it's not a fixed universal number, but rather agreed number on what the website is about (its scope). So I'm not sure if that counts.

Comment: @kenorb if memoryserves, the 22 are the most well-known b/c they are the ones that are the "building blocks of life". the others are artificially created in labs.